# JS: select class inside of <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` on my page.

Inside of the page, that is loaded in the iframe, is this: `<span class="test">TEST</span>`

I would like to change the color of **TEST** to `red`.

---

This is what I wrote:

```
var test = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".test");

test.style.color = "red";
```

---

Seems logical, but it doesn't work. – What's going on?

This is the error message that I'm getting:
[image: Error]

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, for your comment! Could you be so kind, as to maybe show me how I can use this **postMessage-thing** in my example?– I don't really understand it. – I tried implementing it, but I keep getting errors telling me that my code is basically just wrong…

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it seems to work for me. Perhaps its some other issue?

Things to keep in mind:

1. You cant modify a page from a domain that isnt your own (so if the code is running on localhost, you can only modify other loaded files on localhost) This is a CORS issue
2. You need to wait for the IFrame to load the document before modifying it.

Other than that I took a look at your code, and the code on the link below and I tested using querySelector in an iframe and it seemed to work.

Take a look at this if you need more help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

Comment: Hello! – Thank you for your great answer, but I was unfortunately not able to solve it. – 1.  I'm just working with local files. 2. I added a timeout to make sure that that's not the problem, but it didn't change anything. – But, I found an error message in my console and added it to my question, maybe you have an idea on what this could mean? Kind Regards,

Comment: ***Edit:*** Removed link with threat website. Added a better resource. MDN. (w3schools is still at this date (2022.) one of the worst resources to go learn development from. Outdated and bad examples teaching just the worst practices. And it's not even a community-driven site.)

Comment: According to that screenshot this is a CORS issue. I suggest you read over this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin